# What is the correct placement of an adverb of degree/manner with an auxiliary verb and a main verb?

Tags: tense, adverb-placement, sequence-of-tenses

I have two questions relating to the sentence I wrote in bold.

> In 1990, the federal government eliminated its share of contributions to the UI program. **And since then, UI has been entirely funded by contributions from workers and employers.**

**Question 1:** This [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml) and [this](https://www.grammar.com/2-where-do-adverbs-go/) too, says that adverbs such as completely/entirely should be placed between the auxiliary verb and the main verb. So I placed "entirely" in between has been and funded. But when I googled "has been entirely funded" it returned 6,200 results, compared to 23,000 for "has been funded entirely". **What is the correct position for "entirely"?**

**Question 2:** For some reason, I am having difficulty parsing "And **since then**, UI **has been entirely funded"**. I feel the use of "since then" and "has been" with "funded" is not grammatical. What is the correct tense for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both placements are correct and idiomatic. The adverb **entirely** can be placed before or after the verb **funded**. There is no rule that requires adverbs always to be placed before the main verb.

Where you place the adverb is often just a matter of preference, depending on the sentence concerned. You will find examples and explanations at the sites below and at numerous other sites if you google **placement of adverbs**.

Regarding your second query, the tense is correct. The phrase **since then** (or just **since**) connects a point in the past to the present, a construction that is best suited by the present perfect tense.

> He **has lived** in London since Christmas.
>
> She **has worked** at the library for the past six months.

Regrettably, especially on the BBC, one often hears reporters using the past tense when the present perfect is required, in constructions such as:

> The rate fell by one per cent over the past six months. (This is wrong!)

It should be:

> The rate **has fallen** by one per cent over the past six months.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position

https://www.thoughtco.com/adverb-placement-in-english-1211117

Answer (score 1):

**since then ... has been...**

is fine. The concept "from that past point in time until now" is not incompatible with the present perfect.

The placement of **entirely** is a stylistic choice.  Some writers would consider interrupting the verb **has been  funded** as something to avoid.